# Validate that the extracted with a regex date is real

Tags: python, regex, date

I have a regex that extracts dates from strings. But it is not taking into account that there is no 30t of February for example. How can I validate the extracted date, using Python and not complicate the regex more?

This is my regex: `^(?:(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(\,|\.|\/)(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])(\,|\.|\/)(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]))(\,|\.|\/)(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$`

Examples to test on (format DD{separator}MM{separator}(YY)YY:

- 01.12.21
- 31.3.22
- 12.12. - the regex does not work here
- 31/12/22
- 28.02.2021
- 29,02,2020
- 30.02.2003
- 29.02 - the regex does not work here
- 9912/12/200199 - the regex does not work here
- test02-06-13 - the regex does not work here

Comment: With your shown samples please try following regex `^(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(?:\.|\/|,)(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2])(?:\.|\/|,)([0-9]{2,4})` Here is the Online demo: https://regex101.com/r/cOZQV1/1  Obviously this doesn't check about year(range its taking any 2 to 4 digits in regex).

Comment: You should really not use a regex for this, use a date parser. There are subtleties that make it much more robust to use a parser

Comment: Can you suggest anything?

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following regex, written and tested in Python3. I have used `re` library of Python3 here. Then using [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=findall#re.findall) function in it with `re.M`(multiline) flag enabled in it. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/aua5G3/1) for above regex.

```
import re

var="""
01.12.21
31.3.22
12.12.
31/12/22
28.02.2021
29,02,2020
30.02.2003
29.02
9912/12/200199
test02-06-13
"""


re.findall(r'^((?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(?:\.|\/|,)(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2])(?:\.|\/|,)(?:[0-9]{2,4}))$',var,re.M)
['01.12.21', '31.3.22', '31/12/22', '28.02.2021', '29,02,2020', '30.02.2003']
```

One important thing to mention here, this regex is created and tested with shown samples only(will do more tests later on), also for year checks it only checks 2 to 4 digits range in case you have specific range in mind which you want to check or compare then we need to make a tweak in this one.

Comment: @Yana, could you please do let me know if this solution has worked for you(just curious to know since this looks Good question), cheers.